# How can I record off my TV

Tags: tv, recording

My wife and I used to have a TV solution with a TV box from our TV provider, that enabled us to record what ever we wanted of from the TV.

But recently we changed our provider. The new TV provider does not suply such a recording option.

**How can I record what Im seeing on TV for me to watch later?**

I have a 3 year old Sony TV - I cant remember what series of TV it is. But the TV itself does not have a recodring option. There are several HDMI ports in the TV.
FYI I also use a WD Live mediacenter where we store have all out DVDs and Bluerays on an external drive.

Comment: What has this got to do with your computer?

Comment: @DaveRook If this is a misplaced quesiton. Could you help on gettin to the right StackExchange site? It has nothing to with computers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the SE well enough to suggest one (although I don't think there is). The only way this could be on topic here is if you ask how to record it direct to your computer... But to be honest, I would suspect this will become a duplicate (although I have not checked)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to purchase a [Digial Video Recorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_video_recorder) (TV recorder/PVR as it's normally called). Essentially, you plug the cable from your dish/antenna into the appliance, and connect the TV using, for example, an HDMI cable. It will function the same way as the TV box that came with your previous provider.

You need to make sure that you check that it'll be compatible with your existing setup, i.e. the type of cable needed and the dish/antenna.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to by a TV tuner card for your computer and record/playback on the computer, independent of the TV set.  But this is likely as expensive as the stand-alone DVR and more complicated to set up.